# Unable to access connect-mongo's prototyped functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connect, express

Using expressjs and connect-mongo 
I am unable to access any of the prototyped functions that are set in the connect-mongo.js file (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js)

In my case I am trying to access the 'get' on the MongoStore obj function and getting the lovely error:

```
has no method 'get'
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
  Var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

  ///... express code

  app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore(conf.db)
  }));

  //....more express code

  MongoStore.get(sessionId, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

What do you think would be the issue here? Do I need to create the object in another place maybe for the prototyped functions to be picked up?

Comment: Fixed it by creating the "MongoStore" obj outside the scope of the express.session function, and passing in the fully created obj. I will post the answer to this formally here soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to create an instance of MongoStore, and call "get" on it. I'd quick fix your code as below:

```
  var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
  var sessionStore = new MongoStore(conf.db);  // <-- you missed this instantiation 
  ///... express code

  app.use(express.session({
    secret: conf.secret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: sessionStore
  }));

  //....more express code

  sessionStore.get(sessionId, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```